# Adding hard-drive from old computer into new one to use as extra space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I currently have two computers:

- An older rig that I don't use anymore, and
- a new gaming rig that I'm currently using.

The old computer has some USB problem that I haven't been able to fix. But all other parts in the computer work fine.

The hard-drive on the old computer holds important data that I want to save.  My newer computer is also reaching it's space limit.

Would it be possible to take the hard-drive from the old computer and install it into the newer computer in a way that I can access all the files?

I don't have much experience in hardware, But this data is very very important to me.
Can anyone explain if this is possible and how I might go about doing this?

Comment: It should be possible even if you use an external enclosure for the HDD.  Its just a matter of disconnecting the HDD and connecting it to the new computer and/or putting it into the enclosure.

Comment: @Ramhound What exactly do you mean by an external closure?

Comment: [hdd enclosure](http://www.bing.com/search?q=hdd+enclosure&qs=AS&pq=hdd+enclosure&sc=8-13&sp=1&cvid=dbd41debf6df41f6aff156549c3052fa&FORM=QBLH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the old computer is reasonably recent (like, last ten years or so), then this should not be a problem at all. The critical issue is the host interconnect for the hard drive; over the last decade, SATA has virtually all but replaced its predecessor PATA (IDE).

If the hard drive from the old system is a SATA drive, then you should just be able to physically move it to the new system, hook up the cables, and be good to go. Set the BIOS to boot from the new system's existing drive, and you will either be able to access all your files directly, or be able to do so after taking ownership to them from the new system (this requires administrative access).

If the hard drive from the old system is a PATA/IDE drive, things become slightly more involved because virtually no consumer motherboards these days have PATA ports. If that is the case, you'll want to either get a USB-to-PATA external enclosure, or a PATA controller card to install in an expansion slot on your new system's motherboard. Once that is done, the procedure is the same: hook up the drive, possibly set BIOS boot priority, possibly take ownership, and you're done.

Do keep in mind that hard drives don't last forever. If the old one has a few years under its belt, it might be a good idea to simply replace it with a new one. In that case, installing a new drive into the new system and then copying the files from the old system to the new system over the network is probably a better approach.

*And get solid, regular backups in place.* I can't stress this enough if the data is at all valuable or important to you.

Comment: The computer works fine, The USB boards are broken, So I can't plug in any mouse or keyboard.

Comment: @InuKenshi if you have [ps/2 port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) you can get mouse and keybord with this connectors to connect them, instead of using USB to be able to manage the old pc for sharing the drive on network for example

Comment: I've already tried a ps/2 keyboard, But a ps/2 mouse wouldn't work. I went through a thousand different ways to try fix the issue, but nothing would work.

Comment: I took the HDD out and put it in the other computer, It's showing up in the explorer menu now. Though some files I can't access, Such as user files. I did have a password for the old computer, Is that the reason?

Comment: @InuKenshi That's the "take ownership of files" part. It's not related to the password itself. If you cannot find appropriate instructions through your favorite search engine, then please post a separate question mentioning which OS was/is in use on both systems and the exact error message you are getting.